# Como pegar uma variavel dentro de um callback javascript

Tags: javascript

Não consigo passar a variável `x` que está no retorno para outra função.

Declarei a variável global, mas mesmo assim não funciona.

```
function pegaid() {

    var x = "";

    _agile.get_contact("anderocker@hotmail.com", {

       success: function (data) {
          var x= data.id;
          alert(x);
       },
       error: function (data) {
          console.log("error");
       }
    });

    alert(x);

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você declara a variável a primeira vez com `var` e depois redeclara ela dentro da função `success:` da mesma forma `var x = data.id`, ela fica com escopo local dentro da função do `success:`.

O correto seria apenas mudar o valor dentro de `success:`, e não redeclarar com `var`. Ao redeclarar o `x` no `success:`, a linha anterior `var x = "";` é como se nunca tivesse existido. O correto seria:

```
function pegaid() {

    var x = "";

    _agile.get_contact("anderocker@hotmail.com", {

       success: function (data) {
          x= data.id;
          alert(x);
       },
       error: function (data) {
          console.log("error");
       }
    });

    alert(x);

};
```